# Prove that $\{8 k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\} \cup\{8 j+4 : j \in \mathbb{Z}\}=\{x \in \mathbb{Z} : 4 \mid x\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A = \{8k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\} \cup \{8j + 4 : j \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $B = \{x \in \mathbb{Z} : 4 \mid x\}$.
>   Prove that $A = B$.

My initial idea is to consider $B$ and use the fact that $4 \mid x$ to say that $x=4(2b)$ for some integer $b$.

Comment: What you have attempted should be in the question body with the question itself.

Comment: $4\mid x$ does not imply that $x=4(2b)$ for some integer $b$.  Rather, it implies that $x = 4(b)$ for some integer $b$.  Now... it is possible for $b$ to be even, or it is possible for $b$ to be odd.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

Show :

$B \subset A$.

Let $b \in B$, then $4| b$, i.e.

$b=4k$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}.$

1) $k=2k'$, $k' \in \mathbb{Z}$:

$b=4(2k')=8k'$, then $8| b$ and $b \in A$.

2)$k=2k'+1$:

$b=4k=4(2k'+1)= 8k' +4$, and $b \in A$ .

Answer (score 0):

Guideline to a proof (not a complete solution):

Step 1: To prove $A\subseteq B$, let $x\in A$ be arbitrary. Then either $x=8k$ or $8j+4$, for some integer $j,k$.  These are two cases, and in both cases you need to prove that $x\in B$.

Step 2: To prove $B\subseteq A$, let $y\in B$ be arbitrary.  Then $4|y$.  Now prove that $y\in A$.  Sometimes $y$ will be in the set $\{8k:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, while other times $y$ will be in the other part of $A$.  As the hints suggest, it depends on parity.